# Does $A^{2n}= I$ imply that $A^n=I$ or $A^n=-I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_{n}(\Bbb R)$, where $n \ge 2$, then it is true that if $A^{2n}= 0$ , then $A^n$ =0. (since the maximal nilpotency of an $n \times n$ matrix is $n$)
Now, If $A^{2n}= I$, then $A^n = + I$ or $A^n -I$, I think that the second statement is not true, but I can not get any counterexample. Please anyone help me to get this.

Comment: In an odd dimension, just put $\pm 1's$ (some of each) on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the $4\times4$ matrix $A=I_2\oplus R(\pi/4)$, where $R(\theta)\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ denotes the rotation matrix for angle $\theta$. Then $A^8=I$, but $A^4=I_2\oplus-I_2$ is not equal to $\pm I_4$.